# How to create synchronous version of async API

Tags: python, asynchronous

I'm designing an API, that I would like to make asynchronous. On the other hand I would still like to keep a simple to use synchronous version of it. Is there a simple way to achieve this?

I imagine something like a decorator that auto generates blocking wrappers for my `async def` methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to make a decorator that just creates an event loop every time you want to run an async function, but that adds a lot of overhead and confusion.

Another common practice is to create a client that can accept a transport, that way you can just choose to make the transport sync or async, for example, this project https://github.com/aio-libs/aioelasticsearch, which takes the sync elasticsearch pkg, but adds an async transport that you can use with it.

Or elasticsearch's official solution to using async with their pkg
https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/async.html

Anyways, if you ask me I think its better to stick to one thing, if your project benefits from async, just keep the client async.

Answer (score 1):

Running an async function requires an event loop that takes control over the execution.

Just consider every async function you want to convert as a separate program. What you are asking for is then [running an async program](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#running-an-asyncio-program).

```
# async version:
await asyncfunc(arg1, arg2, ...)

# sync version:
asyncio.run(asyncfunc(arg1, arg2, ...))
```

Writing such decorator should be is easy.

Of course, the overhead is big.